# How Paging3's cachedIn(viewModelScope) works in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-paging-3

Hello I am applying Paging3 to my project. I came across the cachedIn() operator while looking at the Paging3 code, and I have one question.

Android official documentation says that cachedIn() caches loaded data using CoroutineScope. I used cachedIn(viewModelScope).

question here.
Until the ViewModel is destroyed, Paging3's data will be held in the ViewModel in the form of a List, so why apply cachedIn()? I would appreciate it if you could give the situation as an example. Since I used a translator, the context may not be smooth. Thank you in advance.